# CORS Error in Vuejs this.$http.get('url') request Vue versio 2.9.6

Tags: vue.js, cors

I am getting the below mentioned error while making a get request to an api on another domain. I understand the that the error is coming up because of the difference in the domains of client and API but it is not working even after trying lot of options.

**Error:**
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com' (redirected from 'https://example.com') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried adding the vue.config.js file with the below mentioned entry but even that does not solve my problem.

I am not using Axiom package rather making the call through this.$http.get() method.

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: '<url?'
  }
}
```

I do not want to have this resolved by the chrome extension as suggested by few people.

Comment: Once you've configured the proxy you will then need to point your client-side HTTP request at the relevant server. The point of using a proxy is that it allows all client-side requests to target the same origin. So rather than pointing at `https://example.com` you would instead make all requests to `http://localhost:8080`, usually with a suitable path on the end to identify which requests are intended for the other server. The proxy will then pass on these requests to the server at `example.com` but the browser won't know anything about it, so CORS will not apply.

Comment: @skirtle I have changed the get url on my client to request the localhost but its not working. The file vue.config.js which is created has been imported in the main.js. How does the url mentioned in the proxy actually gets used  while making the get request? Am i missing something there ?

Comment: You don't import the file `vue.config.js`. That configuration file is automatically picked up by the Vue CLI tool when starting the development server. Make sure you're putting it in the right place or it won't do anything. It also won't be effective if you didn't use Vue CLI to generate the project. See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy. The objective here is to configure the Vue development server to proxy certain requests through to the underlying URL of the API server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the request url (firebase database url in my case) where i had to send the request in the following format -

```
https://example.com/<data>.json?key=<key>
```

I passed the value for data and key and was able to fetch the data without any explicit configuration of vue.config.js.

The CORS error shown up in the console was very misleading in this case.
The takeaway is first we need to try fetching the data directly from postman or similar tools and then try looking for other issues. In my case the data was not getting fetched from postman as well.